# Why still signed in status when press sing out link , and Why still signed out when press sign in link?

Tags: php, html, caching, browser-cache

Why still signed in status when press sing out link , and Why still signed out when press sign in link ?

1. Load `index.php`
2. click `Sign in` link, it's will load to `sign_in.php` and redirect to `index.php` again. But Why still show `You not sign in Sign in` (not sign in status).
   I have to load page (F5) again to show `You was Signed in success Sign out` (signed in status)
3. click `Sign Out` link, it's will load to `sign_out.php` and redirect to `index.php` again. But Why still show `You was Signed in success Sign out` (signed in status).
   I have to load page (F5) again to show `You not sign in Sign in` (not sign in status).

How can i do ? for get sing in / out status by not press `f5` again.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<body>
<?PHP
include("connect.php");
include("header_test.php");
if ($_SESSION['Username']== "")
{ 
?>
 You not sign in  <a href="sign_in.php">Sign in</a>
<?PHP
}
else
{
?>
 You was Signed in success  <a href="sign_out.php">Sign out</a>
<?PHP
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

header_test.php

```
<?PHP
session_start();
?>
```

sign_in.php

```
<?
session_start();
include("connect.php");
$_SESSION["Username"] = "1";
?>
<script language="JavaScript">window.location = 'index.php';</script>
```

sign_out.php

```
<?PHP
include("connect.php");
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("location:index.php");
?>
```

Comment: you're outputting before header in your index.php file, so you need to start the session before your doctype declaration. Error reporting will tell you that, or `headers_sent()`.

Answer (score 0):

Its is happening due to browser's cache. Put the below code to flush the browser's cache in your file before printing any output.

```
//Log out Back
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies.
```